# Как подключить ftp к localhost на open server

Tags: ftp, openserver, notepad++

Мне нужно подключиться к ftp в Notepad++ на Open Server. Ничего в настройках не изменял. Пробовал вводить имя пользователя ftp и пароль такой же ftp (так было указано на официальном сайте), пробовал без имени и пароля - не подключает,пробовал имя польз. без пароля - ничегошеньки. Жду помощи!

Comment: А... На кой фиг заходить с компьютера на него же самого по протоколу удалённого доступа? Это, разумеется, возможно, но зачем?

Comment: Вы  наверное не поняли меня я нахожусь на том же компьютере мне просто нужно что бы в плагине NppFTP для Notepad++ отображалось содержымое папки localhost

Comment: Так зачем вам NppFTP, если вы работаете с локальным компьютером? Зачем лишний слой доступа?

Comment: во первых так намного удобнее открывать файлы, во вторых в NppFTP можно сразу создать файл с любым расшырением (index.php, main.css и тд) а в обычном проводнике windows нельзя так делатть

Comment: Вы могли бы просто поискать другой плагин для дерева файлов, не обременённый дополнительной обёрткой для того, что и так уже есть. Народ, смотрю, советует SherloXplorer. Да и в проводнике Windows можно делать файлы с любым расширением.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен более удобный способ работы с файлами, находящимися на локальном компьютере - советую смотреть не в сторону FTP-клиентов, а в сторону файловых менеджеров.

А именно, вам стоит посмотреть как минимум на вот эти две программы:

- FAR Manager,
- Total Commander

PS Создание файла в FAR Manager - Shift+F4, редактирование - F4. Любимый редактор можно прикрутить через F9 - "Параметры" - "Настройки редактора". Язык интерфейса меняется на русский через F9 - "Options" - "Languages".

Answer (score 0):

Вместо NppFTP для localhost использую плагин Explorer там можно зайти в папку локалхост и создавать  в ней файлы. Тоже удобно